# Read csv file plus processing time series in R

Tags: r, datetime, csv, optimization, time-series

I'm trying to read different csv files that contains a data set (time series) and after that processing it to merge by date all close prices.

I achieved my objective, but as I'm not and expert of R, I would like to know if there are some better ways to do that.

We should have into account that:

1. Each file contains more than 1 million of rows.
2. The files doesn't have the same number of rows (file1= 1.000.000, file2=1.200.00)
3. "Date" and "Time" are different columns and then I need to merge them to get a "Datetime" in a single column.

Here is the code I have:

**1.Read file I'm doing that for each file**

```
eur = read.csv(file = "myFile1.csv", 
               header = FALSE, 
               sep = ",", 
               dec = ".")

names(eur)=c("date","time","high", "low", "open", "close", "vol")
```

**2. Merge "Date" and "Time" columns to get "Datetime" column**

```
timestamp <- strptime(paste(eur$date, eur$time), format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M")
timestamp = data.frame(timestamp)
eurNuevo <- cbind(timestamp,eur$close)
names(eurNuevo)=c("datetime","close")
```

At this point, as each file contains different number of rows i can't do a cbind because it's showing an error. So i thought that I could convert each vector to a time series object and then merge it and delete na rows.

**3. Convert to TS and then merge it**

```
eurts = ts(eurNuevo)                # time series 
pairs = ts.union(eurts,another_ts)  # Union by date 
pairs = na.omit(pairs)              # Delete NA
```

I think that it should have another way to do that better and faster. I would appreciate if someone could help me.